# TWO StoryBoards, ONE Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

Because we are working on a team, we really need to have multiple story boards in an iOS application project.

I read somewhere that you cannot have multiple story boards if you're using a Tab Bar Controller but I believe I made it work.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good practice?
2. Do you see anything unsave in the code?
3. Can you forsee any errors down the road?

I have two story boards, `Main.Storyboard` and `Settings.storyboard`. Notice that in MAIN, I embedded the entry point to a new Tab Bar Controller and added two views via Interface Builder.

[image: MAIN.STORYBOARD]

and:

[image: SETTINGS.STORYBOARD]

**Programically**, I want to add a third tab which goes to a `UIViewController` **in another** story board. I did this with the following code (in viewDidLoad in the Main's ViewController code):

```
var settingsStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
var initialViewController:UIViewController = settingsStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SettingsMain") as UIViewController

var viewsInTBC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers
viewsInTBC?.append(initialViewController)
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = viewsInTBC
```

Surprisingly, it works! I can actually see that View when I tap on the third item in the view controller (although it doesn't show an icon or text) - which brings me to my last question:

4. How can I add an icon and a title since I can't seem to figure it out after I add the view to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ad. 4

If you want to set properly icon you should:

1. At start attach new `UIViewController` by storyboard to your `UITabBarController`.
2. Set proper icon for this tab.
3. Remove connection.
4. Copy and pase this controller to the second storyboard and set it as initial view controller.

Or just add button programically (XML code):

```
    <!--Settings-->
    <scene sceneID="Cac-NB-uhR">
        <objects>
            <navigationController definesPresentationContext="YES" id="BkC-WO-8Bx" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Settings" image="icoAxis" id="PEg-DC-QVf"/>
                <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="4RT-g8-Hp3">
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </navigationBar>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="bvJ-l1-eMt" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="FJJ-h4-ftX"/>
                </connections>
            </navigationController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Ane-ce-dgm" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="947" y="1037"/>
    </scene>
```

At start i got my Navigation controller in main.storyboard. Now in derived from `UITabBarViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard *settingsStoryboard = [StoryboardManager getSettingsStoryboard];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [settingsStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [self.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    [arr addObject:navigationController];
    [self setViewControllers:arr];
}
```

### EDIT

### Answering to your other questions:

### Ad 1.

**Is this a good practice?**
Yes it is. If you are using storyboards in your project and your project reachs tens of view controllers kept in one storyboard may cause:

1. The storyboard will open very slowly e.g. 10 seconds. It really iritates developer.
2. Merge conflicts when many developers would add/modify/delete controller in that storyboard.
3. Sometimes happen critical problem with storyboard and editor may not able to open it. In some cases you may be forced to revert the changes in the storyboard. Using multiple storyboards decrease the chance that you may loose done changes.

### Ad 2.

**Do you see anything unsave in the code?**
Your code looks fine. The only thing that may worry me is that you use name of the storyboard directly. If you use settings in more than one place you should "pack" getting controller in separate method/class. The problem may occur if you will rename storyboard name - then you will have to find all occurances to change them. If you will miss one of them, then some problems may occur. Anyway I don't think extracting that methos is obligatory.

### Ad 3.

**Can you forsee any errors down the road?**
I don't see any problems that may happen.

Comment: I don't think it's standard practice to modify the XML of the Storyboard directly.

Comment: That's why I showed the steps how to do that without manual source modification.

Comment: The listed steps do not seem to make sense. I would end up with two of the same controller, just one would be in another Storyboard?

Comment: Sorry I wrote "second controller" but it should be "second storyboard". I had exact the same situation as you have, but previously I had all connection in one storyboard. By doing cut-paste and doint `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` etc. i didn't have any problems with bar icons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is practical. Separating storyboards to modules is great idea.

Instead of hacking yourself, this project can save you a lot of time: [RBStoryboardLink](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink). The author has a good write up about tips for using storyboards: [UIStoryboard Best Practices](http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.jp/2012/01/uistoryboard-best-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do any hacks....
You create a tab bar in one storyboard like this
[image]

Then you create a storyboard reference
[image]

And you add it to your tab bar like so
[image]

Then you change the storyboard you want to use:

Then WALAAAAHHH! YOU HAVE TWO STORYBOARDS ONE TAB CONTROLLER!
YAYYY!

Comment: Then how to use a particular viewcontroller from the linked storyboard ?